# Need to assign selected linkbutton value in datalist to label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I need to assign a value of linkbutton selected from datalist to a label.

How can i do this?

.aspx code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                style="margin-left: 5px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Italic="False" ToolTip="click to open"></asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>


        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="item" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

.aspx.cs

```
 protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    item.Text = DataList1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please post your current code and detail what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done like this :

```
<asp:Label1 ID="Label1" runat="server" 

Text='<%# Bind("your datafield") %>'
```

Comment: no i want to assign the value out of the datalist with particular selected/ clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myLink = DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("LinkButton2") as LinkButton;
    if (myLink != null)
    {
        item.Text = myLink.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is it 'not working'? Please put a little more effort in if you expect people to help you.

Comment: i put your code but when i click to datalist item the value of label need to be change but its not it remains as it is... no errors nothing..

Comment: It's not a case of whether or not there are errors. The code above is correct, so something else is going on. You need to find out what. For example, does it enter the `if` block? Does `myLink.Text` actually have a value? Put a breakpoint in that function, debug and investigate.

Comment: @raman will you help me one more please...??
i need a code for youtube thumbnail with play button after i click to play the video will play in popup... i had a project n have to submit it 2 days after...

Comment: @Gaurav Read my last comment. You need to debug the method and find out what's going wrong. If you don't know how to do this, now is the time to learn.

Comment: @AntP: i tried n had a solution just deleted my last sqlsource n update it.. :)  thanks for your help... really appreciate...
now will u help me one more time as i wrote in above comment i had problem will u plz help me in solution...plz

Comment: @Gaurav Please post a new question if you need help with something else.

Comment: @AntP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315110/need-a-code-for-youtube-thumbnail-with-play-button-after-i-click-to-play-the-vid